# How to use IF EXISTS in SQL (ifexists update, else insert in SQL)

Tags: c#, sql-server, if-statement, exists, insert-update

```
string searched = TextBox1.Text; // for example, text is 4477

...

sorgu.CommandText = "IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Pins] WHERE Pin =' " + searched.ToString() + " ') BEGIN UPDATE [Pins] SET SAY= SAY+1, Pin = ' " + searched.ToString() + " ' END ELSE BEGIN INSERT INTO Pins(SAY,Pin) VALUES (+1,' " + searched.ToString() + " ') END";

...
```

I am using SAY for counting the number of searches.

This code is changing all records on column (Pins) to searched text.

Where/What is my fault?

Comment: You don't have a where clause on your update statement. The bigger problem is that this is a textbook example of sql injection. You need to parameterize your queries before bobby tables comes for a visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: I would move this to a stored procedure so you have better control over what is happening and you can debug/maintain it without having to parse this big nasty string into something legible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a where to not update all records. This would fix it.... but is a horrible query.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Pins] WHERE Pin = 'searched.ToString()')
BEGIN 
    UPDATE [Pins] SET SAY = SAY + 1
    WHERE [Pin] = 'searched.ToString() '
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Pins(SAY, Pin) VALUES (1, 'searched.ToString()') 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code, you're saying

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT Statement) UPDATE ALL ROWS
```

The correct way to do this with EXISTS is

```
UPDATE TABLE
WHERE EXISTS(Correlated SELECT Statement)
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `WHERE` clause.

I would also prefer using `Parameters` instead of string concatenated query (which makes your code open to SQL injection attacks)

```
string searched = TextBox1.Text; // for example, text is 4477

sorgu.CommandText = "IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Pins] WHERE Pin = @searched) BEGIN UPDATE [Pins] SET SAY=SAY+1 WHERE Pin = @searched END ELSE BEGIN INSERT INTO Pins(SAY,Pin) VALUES (1, @searched) END";
sorgu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searched", TextBox1.Text);
```